# Making JSF website multilingual

Tags: jsf, encoding, rendering, special-characters, multilingual

Trying to make JSF web application multilingual. For that purpose cover all the HTML code with `<f:view>` tags:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns= ... >

<f:view locale="#{actionsContainer.languageDetails.locale}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <f:loadBundle basename="messages.Messages" var="key" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h:outputText value="#{key.myText}" />
  </body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Than in resources I have several 'Messages.properties' files with a translations to some languages:

- Messages_en.properties
- Messages_es.properties
- Messages.properties // default

The sample content of this files 'Messages_es.properties' is:

```
myText=España
```

Let's take, my locale is "es", and than Spanish translation file loads it's value and renders to the screen. However, the special characters (eg 'ñ') doesn't display properly in a browser output. Instead of special Spanish letters I am getting something like this "Ã³".

I have tried to save .properties file with UTF-8 encoding, without BOM. And the output has been changed to something like this "".

**And so the question is how do I get this special any language letters in an output?!**

Answer (score 2):

Properties files are by default read using the ISO-8859-1 encoding. You need the JDK native2ascii tool to convert UTF-8 properties files to ISO-8859-1 properties files and then use those instead.

In JSF you can however also specify a custom `ResourceBundle` with a `Control` wherein you overridde the reading of properties files to use UTF-8 instead. See also [this article](http://jdevelopment.nl/java/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/).

Comment: I have tried to replace all those special letters with \uXXXX format, however -webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) displays an error: Entity 'u00E7' not defined

Comment: That's weird since they should not be resolved by the webbrowser, but by the webserver. How exactly are you loading and displaying them? Did you check the linked article how it could (and should) be done?

Answer (score 0):

when working with resource bundles, consider using ResourceBundle Editor plugin for eclipse (http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-rbe/).